# two versions of emacs on mac osx - where are they

Tags: osx, path, aliases

This has got to be a silly question...

From a terminal window, to start emacs which comes with mac osx (version 22.1.1), I just type

```
> emacs
```

First set of questions: where is this emacs installed?  where is the alias defined?

Now, I just discovered (!) how old this version is, and so I installed the latest version from http://emacsformacosx.com.  When I type

```
> emacs
```

I still launch the old version (22.1.1) and not the new one.  On the other hand, if I type in a terminal window

> open -a emacs

then the new version (25.3.1) is launched.

Second set of questions: why is that?  where is the alias for this other emacs? how does the system choose which version to launch?

Answer (score 2):

It is one question per customer / thread ...

As to the first question, the great thing about Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/ is that it is a self-contained installation.  The executable is inside the packaged **Emacs.app** wherever you installed it.

If you placed the **Emacs.app** inside the root `/Applications` folder, then your path to the *Emacs* executable is:  `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`

If you placed the **Emacs.app** inside the root `/Applications` folder, then your path to the *emacsclient* executable is:  `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient`

[Within `../Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/..` I see multiple different builds for various versions of OSX.  I have only ever used the generic executables at the paths listed above.  Feel free to try out an OSX version specific executable that matches your system version type ...]

OSX ships with an outdated version of Emacs with an absolute path of `/usr/bin/emacs`

You can always type the absolute path in the terminal to the desired Emacs executable, or you can set up an alias (which is a different question beyond the scope of the one question per customer / thread general rule).

For the location of executables within the $PATH of the terminal, you can type `which NAME_OF_EXECUTABLE` -- in this example, typing `which emacs` in the terminal produces a result of `/usr/bin/emacs`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!  Sorry, I was only being rhetorical when I asked "two" questions.  There really was only one: how do two versions of emacs coexist.  As to creating an alias, note that I did not ask the question how to do that in the post, as evidently this is a completely different question - and one that has nothing to do with emacs (in fact like my original question(s)!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the system knows which version to launch, but to open the newly installed Emacs from terminal, type `emacs23`.

Comment: I would still like to understand how things work.  In fact, when I type emacs23, it doesn't work, because I haven't defined the alias emacs23 for the version of emacs that I want.  And that brings another question, which is where and how to define such aliases, but I have to dig a little bit more before posting a question...